# Having trouble looping through HTML tbody and creating a DataFrame from a table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is the URL/Table that I'm having trouble with:

https://www.naturalstattrick.com/teamtable.php?fromseason=20222023&thruseason=20222023&stype=2&sit=all&score=all&rate=y&team=all&loc=B&gpf=410&fd=&td=

The HTML structure looks like:

```HTML
<table>
    <colgroup>
        <col />
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Python:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

##### LOAD IN NHL TEAM STATS ######

# Send a GET request to the Natural Stat Trick website and retrieve the HTML content
nhl_team_stats = "https://www.naturalstattrick.com/teamtable.php?fromseason=20222023&thruseason=20222023&stype=2&sit=all&score=all&rate=y&team=all&loc=B&gpf=410&fd=&td="
nhl_team_stats_response = requests.get(nhl_team_stats)
nhl_team_stats_html_content = nhl_team_stats_response.content

# Use BeautifulSoup to parse the HTML content
nhl_team_stats_soup = BeautifulSoup(nhl_team_stats_html_content, "html.parser")

# Find the table containing the NHL schedule data
nhl_team_stats_table = nhl_team_stats_soup.find("table", attrs={"id": "teams"})

# Extract the table headers
nhl_team_stats_headers = []
for thead in nhl_team_stats_table.find_all('thead'):
    for tr in thead.find_all("tr"):
        for th in tr.find_all("th"):
            nhl_team_stats_headers.append(th.text.strip())

nhl_team_stats_headers[0] = "ID"

print(nhl_team_stats_headers)

# Extract the table rows
nhl_team_stats_rows = []
teams_list = []
tbody = nhl_team_stats_table.find("tbody")
for tr in tbody.find_all("tr"):
    row = []
    for td in tr.find_all(["td"]):
        cell_text = td.text.strip()
        row.append(cell_text)
    nhl_team_stats_rows.append(row)
    teams_list.append(row[1])

print(nhl_team_stats_rows)

# print(teams_list)

# Convert the nhl_team_stats_rows to a DataFrame
# nhl_team_stats_df = pd.DataFrame(nhl_team_stats_rows, nhl_team_stats_headers)

# Get the mean xGF/60
# mean_gf = pd.to_numeric(nhl_team_stats_df[22], errors='coerce').mean()

# Convert the teams_list to a DataFrame
# teams_df = pd.DataFrame(teams_list, columns=["Team"])
```

Is anything jumping out at anyone because I feel like I am looping through the table correctly? Printing out the headers, it looks like the headers loop works fine. It's just the rows I am having an issue with. It seems like it's duplicating data which makes me think there are too many loops, but I haven't found a way to get the data without duplicates and a list length that equals 32. Any ideas?

Comment: I didn't scrutinize it, but `dfs = pd.read_html(nhl_team_stats)`, or maybe `dfs = pd.read_html(nhl_team_stats, index_col=0)` seem to work really well.

Comment: Wow you're one beautiful human being